# Передвинуть маркеры Yandex Map

Tags: yandex-maps-api

```js
$.getJSON("virt-xml.php",function(data){

$.each(data.markers, function(k, marker) {

dep = new ym.Placemark([marker.pos.x1, marker.pos.y1], { hintContent: marker.start + ' - ' + marker.place_start},
{
 iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: 'maps/images/radio-red.svg',
    iconImageSize: [8, 8],
    iconImageOffset: [-4, -4]
        });
    map.geoObjects.add(dep);
```

Получаю новые координаты маркеров. Нужно передвинуть маркеры. Не удалить и поставить, а именно переместить. Прошу помощи!

Comment: `dep.geometry.setCoordinates([55.00, 37.00]);`

Comment: пробовал, но передвигается только последний загруженный маркер, не пойму только почему, вроде перебираю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы переместить метки нужно использовать:

```
marker.geometry.setCoordinates([55.00, 37.00]);
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcauvxfy/

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

За это отвечает настройка

```
draggable: true
```

https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/dg/concepts/geoobjects